# Problem to automatically update list of files on Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Why does the Finder (MacOS) not automatically update the list of files when the download is finished? How to solve this problem?

Actually, I always need to click on another folder and back to the Downloads folder to see the new file.

Comment: Finder calls are asynchronous now. I've sometimes found the AppleScript ||||do shell script "killall Finder"|||| to be handy in getting things to show up promptly. Those vertical lines are just to offset the code in the comment.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger You don't need to use vertical lines. You can use inline code formatting instead: `\`do shell script "killall Finder"\``, which produces `do shell script "killall Finder"`.

Comment: Never met tilda before here.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger @haykam  Stop killing Finder.  It’s not necessary here, and why would you run a shell script command from AppleScript…?  Why not just use a shell script ?  But AppleScript is better for two things: `tell app "Finder" to update every item in the front Finder window`, which does the refresh.  And next time, instead of killing, consider just quitting: `tell app "Finder" to quit`.

Comment: @CJK I like killing. I run it a an Applescript because then I can save it in FastScripts, and execute as a keyboard shortcut, rather than typing it in terminal.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger You can create keyboard shortcuts by using Automator as a service running that shell script.  Or, even better, you can set the user defaults preferences for Finder to reveal the Quit menu item and then you can ⌘-Q to quit Finder gracefully and like any other app.

Comment: @CJK You're right, I could use Automator. However, I got used to writing AppleScript long before Automator came around, so I don't like the extra level of complication and obfuscation it requires. -Just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Open your dowload folder and sort by date added. Under the View Menu select show view options. This opens a pane like the one shown below.

[image]

You want to make sure your 1st 4 settings are identicle to the ones shown above in the top red rectangle and the "Show Columns"  settings has the "Data Added box checked.

Now when you download a file the name should appear almost immediately at the top of the window.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. It is very simple:

> Hold down the OPTION key and right-click on the Finder icon in the Dock, choose “Relaunch”.

Reference: http://osxdaily.com/2013/08/30/refreshing-finder-windows-in-mac-os-x/